# How would you suppress scientific notations in a pandas dataframe so that the numbers appear like in this list[1,123.89, 19.4], unique dec precision?n

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scientific-notation

I am using this function:

```
pd.set_option("display.float_format", lambda x: "%.2f" % x)
```

But all the numbers on my dataFrame are fixed to 2 decimal position which is not what I need. I just want them each value to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `object` to the `dtype` parameter in [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'nums': [1,123.89, 19.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=object)

print(df)

     nums
0       1
1  123.89
2    19.4
```

If you want the `dtype` change to affect only a specific column, you can construct your `df` as follows:

```
data = {'nums': pd.Series([1,123.89, 19.4], dtype=object),
        'nums2': [1,123.89, 19.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

     nums   nums2
0       1    1.00
1  123.89  123.89
2    19.4   19.40
```